# how to split disks(Nvme, SSD, HDD) between windows and linux

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, nvme

I have a PC setup which has following disks:

- 120GB Nvme Storage (PCIe gen 3)
- 240GB SSD (WD Green)
- 1TB HDD (5400 rpm)
- 320GB HDD (5400 rpm)

that i want to have Linux(Ubuntu) and windows installations on it( and also a little free space to test other OSs).
My Setup has following components:

1. Ryzen 7 5700G APU
2. Corsair VENGEANCE 2x8GB 3600MHz memory (planning to add two other sticks of the same model later)
3. Asus Prime B550-Plus MotherBoard

So, my problem is

> how to divide storage to get the best performance out of these storage pieces

Considering, at first i am an Ubuntu user and a programmer so i usually spend my time using Linux, and just sometimes switch to windows for some gaming and other windows tools( which is not my first priority).

On laptops with a SSD and a HDD i just simply make 3 partitions on SSD for `Windows C:/`, `Linux /`  and `Swap area` respectively(and HDD for Mass Storage), but what is the best way to do with Nvme + SSD? Should i separate Linux directories?

What is the best way?

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1):

As you are going to use Ubuntu as your main Operating System ( OS ), and it doesn't need as much space for the OS itself as Windows does, I would suggest you install Ubuntu on your Nvme drive and Windows on your SSD.   
                                                                                                                                                                       If the other drives are fixed in the system you can use one for your /home ( Ubuntu ) partition and the other one as storage for your other documents. You can specify in Windows that your documents, pictures, music and videos are on another disk, so I would take advantage of that.  
 I always suggest to keep your documents and OS's seperated. In case you have to install the OS again it would not lead to loss of documents, pictures, music- or videocollection. 
Your games on the other hand I would not put them on the HDD because they are much slower than the SSD ( 5400 rpm ).

Comment: thanks for your answer. you said "You can specify in Windows that your documents, ... are on another disk". how is it done? and is it like having "Users" directory on another disk? I mean, can i prevent my C:\ partition growing as time pass( by locating things outside that partition)? so i can install it on a little partition on Nvme.

Comment: Not the whole "user"directory, but your document, pictures, music and videos, yes. In explorer you can go to c:\windows\users\username\my documents, rightclick on the directory, choose properties and change the path from C:\... to for example D:\My Documents. Then it should make the directories on your D-drive. And I would not put Windows on the Nvme drive ( size is small ). I haven't used Windows in ages but it worked in my Windows 10. I don't know if it will work in Win11.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of possible variables, but here's my take...

- 120GB Nvme Storage (PCIe gen 3)

  - Ubuntu (for speed)
  - /swapfile for swap (not a swap partition)
- 240GB SSD (WD Green)

  - Windows
- 1TB HDD (5400 rpm)

  - Partition into NTFS (to share files with Windows), and EXT4 partitions (for games/docs/pictures/music/etc)
- 320GB HDD (5400 rpm)

  - remove this drive

**Note**: Boot desired OS from the GRUB menu... **but this might change with Ubuntu 22.04**... without mods.

**Note**: Check for latest BIOS for your **Asus Prime B550-Plus**. `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: The 320 is good for storing pictures and music.

Comment: @JoepieEs Huh? In **my** answer, that's what the 1TB drive is for.

Comment: I understand, but if you put that on the 320 there is more space for video on the 1 TB.

Comment: @JoepieEs Why are you challenging me and my answer? **My** answer configures the computer the best way I see fit... and there's no need for the 320G HDD. The user can do whatever they wish. Please make sure that your **own** answer is the best it can be.

Comment: @ heynnema I'm not challenging you nor your answer. It is just the way I see it, and how I had my things configured. I needed a lot of space for video-editing. Your configuration is more silent and draws less power, so that is an advantage. And of course, the user makes the choice how he or she wants to configure his or her computer, no doubt about that.